# x86 Assembly - Add Two 64 Bit Numbers

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to write this code in x86 assembly (X[i] and C are 64 bit numbers). Assume memory address to A[i] is stored in `ebx` and C is stored in `edx`.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    A[i] = A[i] + C
}
```

I have a pretty good grasp on how to access the values in memory. Because I have 32 bit registers, I believe I need to do two additions: one for the lower 32 bits of each operand and one for the upper 32 bits.

So something like:

```
mov rax, [A[i]_bits0_15]
add rax, [C_bits0_15]
mov [A[i]_bits0_15], rax

mov rbx, [A[i]_bits16_31]
adc rbx, [C_bits16_31]
mov [A[i]_bits16_31], rbx
```

Am I on the right track? I am not sure how to do the proper notation for adding the lower/upper 32 bits from memory so that would be helpful to see as well.

Comment: You have a confusing mix of sizes. You mention 64 bit numbers in the title, 32 bit registers, and your example code uses 64 bit registers but implies it wants to read 16 bits of each number.

Comment: Those are 64-bit registers, you just need one qword `add` on x86-64.  (Unless you want to implement 128-bit integer math).  You can of course use dword add + adc, but that's less efficient.  Look at gcc output (https://godbolt.org/) for `unsigned long long` with `-m32`, or for `unsigned __int128` with normal 64-bit code.

Answer (score 0):

No different than grade school.

```
 011
 1234
+5678
=====
 6912
```

break it into halves

```
 11
  34
+ 78
=====
 112

 12
+56
=====
 68
```

you need to move the carry over to the upper addition

```
 11   <--- carry out hanging off the left
  34
+ 78
=====
  12

  1  <--- carry in from lower level addition
 12
+56
=====
 69
```

and there is the 6912.

X86 has a carry out bit and should have an add with carry instruction to include that bit (zero or one) into the next level addition.

You can obviously add numbers that are as wide as you have storage for 8, 16, 32, 64 bits at a time depending on the instruction you choose. 1 million bits, one billion bits, etc...